# Parser Exception for format EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss a z

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I'm getting parser exception on trying to parse string value:

```
"Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PST"
```

To format:

```
"EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss a z"
```

This is the program sample:

```
DateTime.parse("Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PDT", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a z"));
```

And this is the error message:

```
Invalid format: "Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PDT" is malformed at "PDT"
```

---

this is my sample program

```
String str = "Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PDT"; 
DateTimeFormatter formatterDateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss a z");
try{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(str, formatterDateTime);
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It works for me - although if this is meant to be Pacific time, it should be PDT rather than PST. Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please, add some code and the exact error or you're unlikely to get any answer.

Comment: What locale do you use? I think you have to explicitly provide Locale.US

Comment: shouldn't `YYYY` be small ? i.e `yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JodaTime [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.

However `SimpleDateFormat` does support parsing of timezones.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY h:mm:ss aa zzz");
Date date = format.parse("Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PST");
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by marba, the error most likely is caused by using Java 7 specific pattern with a Java 6.

Your code for parsing the date can look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss aa zzz");
Date d = df.parse("Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PST");
```

To test that the parsed date is the same as the provided date:

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Pitcairn"));
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Prints:

```
Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PST
```

Refer to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more patterns.

Comment: How do you know that `YYYY` is causing the exception?

Comment: Tried it myself and checked the Javadoc, there is no pattern for `YYYY`.

Comment: In Java 7 it is legal: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: And that might be the problem (that he is using Java 6), but we don't know that.

Comment: Well, if someone has created a question on SO, pasted some code and claims he gets an exception in this code then I think we can assume that the exception actually comes from this code. Also if the OP were not getting an exception then I think he would not ask in the first place.

Comment: You're welcome. If you update your link to point to Java 7 I will give you my +1. And also point out that the error most likely is caused by using Java 7 specific pattern with a Java 6 JRE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30007/discussion-between-adam-siemion-and-maba)

Comment: There's nothing to continue :-)

Answer (score 0):

What locale do you use? I think you have to explicitly provide `Locale.US` as a second parameter to `SimpleDateFormat`.

For Joda-Time library you can use following code to adjust locale:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss a z").withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Update: Just found [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393765/joda-datetime-parser-error), looks like you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` instead. Joda-Time parser does not support time zones:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss a z");
Date d = df.parse("Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PDT");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You have used `Y` (which specifies *Week year*) instead of `y` (which specifies *Year*). Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about symbols. Learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34691582/10819573).
2. Your date-time string is in English and therefore your code won't work in an expected manner if you run it on a JVM with non-English `Locale`. Date-time parsing/formatting types are `Locale`-sensitive. Learn more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40025528/10819573).

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, u h:m:s a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PST", dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2006-07-27T22:10:02-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

In case you need to convert this object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
java.util.Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Solution using the legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, y h:m:s a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse("Thursday, July 27, 2006 10:10:02 PM PST");
        //...
    }
}
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>