# Java: How to convert string with month name to DateTime?

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, datetime-format

I've seen answers that let me convert when the format is like

`"14/02/1952 14:52:22"`

by using DateTimeFormatter

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

How do I apply the same idea to strings of this format:

`"Sunday, September 29, 2013 7:59:58 AM PDT"`

I am trying

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a zzz";
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

but it's complaining about this.

Comment: Please read the javadoc of `DateTimeFormat` and `DateTimeFormatter`. It's all in there.

Comment: I recommend SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @hooknc Why would you?

Comment: thanks Sotirios Delimanolis. I edited my question with what I'm trying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 2018/Java 10

```
String value = "Sunday, September 29, 2013 7:59:58 AM PDT";
String format = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a zzz";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern(format)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(value, formatter);
System.out.println(zdt);
System.out.println(zdt.format(formatter));
```

Which prints

```
2013-09-29T07:59:58-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
Sunday, September 29, 2013 7:59:58 AM PDT
```

## Original answer

You need to change the expected format to meet the requirements as specified by the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String value = "Sunday, September 29, 2013 7:59:58 AM PDT";
String format = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a zzz";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(value);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Mon Sep 30 00:59:58 EST 2013
Sunday, September 29, 2013 7:59:58 AM PDT
```

Comment: thanks, apparently this doesn't work for DateTimeFormatter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393765/joda-datetime-parser-error

Comment: @Popcorn So stick with `SimpleDateFormat` for the time being.  Get the value into a `Date` object and then start taking advantage of the JodaTime API's from there