# Cannot initialize Joda DateTime with Dutch Day month year String

Tags: java, jodatime

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
    f = f.withLocale(Locale.US);
    f.parseDateTime("13 januari 2016");

    DateTime date = new DateTime(f);
    date.getDayOfYear();
}
```

The month is in Dutch, not in English.

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "13 januari 2016" is malformed at "uari 2016"
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

How can I properly initialize this Joda DateTime? 
Many thanks guys!

Comment: Try to replace `f.parseDateTime("13 januari 2016");` with `f.parseDateTime("13 jan 2016");`

Comment: @Dhruv that doesn't work. And I have 12 months, each length varies.

Comment: I thought it is the problem due to your different DateTimeFormatter. In that you are having MMM format month, and you are passing value in it as `januari`. I think it should be like, `jan., feb., maart, apr., mei, juni, juli, aug., sept., oct., nov., dec.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [joda DateTime parser error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393765/joda-datetime-parser-error)

Comment: Sure, but these are the values that I have: Januari, Februari, Maart, April, Mei, Juni, Juli, Augustus, September, Oktober, November, December. And it has to work with these month values. Is that not possible somehow?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Because I have used Joda library with English month name. If anything I will get, I will surely add comment here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the appropriate `Locale` for the language you expect. Use it to construct a `DateTimeFormat` with the appropriate pattern. Then parse your date string.

For example

```
Locale dutch = Locale.forLanguageTag("nl-nl");
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy").withLocale(dutch);
DateTime date = f.parseDateTime("13 januari 2016");
```

---

I don't know what you were trying to do with

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(f);
```

That `DateTime` constructor expects an `Object` representing an instant.

> The recognised object types are defined in `ConverterManager` and
>   include `ReadableInstant`, `String`, `Calendar` and `Date`. The `String` 
>   formats are described by `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`.

`DateTimeFormat` is neither of these.

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time in maintenance mode

The [Answer by Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37302455/642706) is correct. But beware that the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with its team advising migration to the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

When parsing a string, specify [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

- The human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
- The cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Rather than specify a formatting pattern explicitly, you may let java.time automatically localize. To localize, specify a [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.

```
String input = "13 januari 2016";
Locale l = new Locale ( "nl", "NL" );  // Dutch language, Netherlands country.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale ( l );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input, f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input );
System.out.println ( "ld.toString(): " + ld );
```

> input: 13 januari 2016
>
> ld.toString(): 2016-01-13

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).